# Disqus: get thread ID or URL to show comments on a separate page

Tags: disqus

Instead of showing comments right on the page I want to put a link to the corresponding thread page on disqus.com. Two questions:

1. How to get the Disqus thread ID (or thread URL) for a page?**
2. Is it possible to create such a page if no comments were previously posted into the thread?**

---

Explanational info:

Disqus has a separate page for each website where you can see all commented pages: 
`https://disqus.com/home/forum/%SITENAME%/`, where `%SITENAME%` is a forum name used by Disqus for you website.

Each *commented*(!) page there has it's own URL like this: `https://disqus.com/home/forum/%SITENAME%/__1234/` where `__1234` is an example of an internal ID (thread ID?) Disqus uses. Note, that this is NOT a page ID set via JS variable `this.page.identifier`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I ended up with.

**1. How to get the Disqus thread ID (or thread URL) for a page?**

They call it a thread slug. It could be taken form `threads/detail` endpoint. See the docs here: https://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/details/

Here is the jQuery ajax code example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/details.json", // API endpoint
    data: {
        api_key: '%YOUR_API_KEY%',
        forum : '%YOUR_FORUM_NAME%',
        thread: 'ident:%PAGE_IDENTIFIER%', // get thread by identifier
        thread: 'link:' + %PAGE_URL%,        // OR get thread by page url
    },
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'jsonp', // for cross-domain requests
    success: function (result) {
        var slug = result.response.slug; //this will contain the thread slug

        // let's update the link somewhere on the page
        $('.disqus-comments-link')
             .attr('href','https://disqus.com/home/discussion/%YOUR_FORUM_NAME%/' + slug + '/');
    }
});
```

**2. Is it possible to create a thread if no comments were previously posted?**

It is more complicated. If you will use the code above for the page where Disqus scripts were never run, the thread slug will be empty since it needs to be created first.

Thread page could be created in two ways:

1. By running Disqus [initialisation scripts](https://help.disqus.com/installation/universal-embed-code) on a page at least once.
2. Manually via `threads/create` API endpoint. It requires authentication and currently is in beta. See docs here: https://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/create/

**Result:** Instead of creating the thread manually, I just run the Disqus initialisation script and then get the thread slug via API. That's it.